# Drop Down Menu (Sidebar)

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

I've put together the code below to load marker data from my SQL database which correctly shows all of the information held.

I'd like to now include a drop down menu that shows the markers by their 'Location Name' and when the user selects the location the associated marker bounces. I know from some of the information that I've found that this is a sidebar? Could someone perhaps please point me in the right direction as to how I would go about adapting my code to include this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>All Locations</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function load() { 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
zoom:6, 
mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
}); 

// Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
downloadUrl("phpfile.php", function(data) { 
var xml = data.responseXML; 
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address"); 
var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon"))); 
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
map: map, 
position: point, 
}); 
} 
}); 
} 

function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
new XMLHttpRequest; 

request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (request.readyState == 4) { 
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
callback(request, request.status); 
} 
}; 

request.open('GET', url, true); 
request.send(null); 
} 

function doNothing() {} 

//]]> 

</script> 

</head> 

<body onLoad="load()"> 
<div id="map" 
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Map My Finds - All Locations</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/alllocationsstyle.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <a href="javascript:;" title="Locations" onclick="animate(this)">Location Name</a> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            0: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            1: {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

            function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap' 
            }); 

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("mapmyfindsloadalllocations.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker"); 
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
            var finds = markers[i].getAttribute("finds");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lat")), 
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("osgb36lon")));
            var icon = customIcons[finds] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
            map: map, 
            position: point,
            title: locationname + ' - ' + address,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
            }); 
            } 
            }); 
            } 
            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 

            </script> 
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function animate(element) {    
            var marker = getMarkerByName(element.title);    
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);    
            setTimeout(function() { marker.setAnimation(null); }, 200); }  
            function getMarkerByName(name) {    
            // retrieve and return the marker from where you stored it } 
            </script> 
            </head> 
            <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div>
                <label></label>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:
Associate each location name with the link in the drop down menu.
Store the marker for each location.
When you click a link from the drop down menu, retrieve the marker associated with that location and simply call a function that animates it:

```
 ....
<!-- assuming this is an item from the menu -->
 <a href="javascript:;" title="locationName" onclick="animate(this)">Location Name </a>
 ....
```

The script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function animate(element) {
   var marker = getMarkerByName(element.title);
   marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
   setTimeout(function() { marker.setAnimation(null); }, 200);
}

function getMarkerByName(name) {
   // retrieve and return the marker from where you stored it
}
</script>
...
```

Something like that

**UPDATE:**

There is basically no change... when you click the link, highlight it and call the animate function.
For highlighting the correct link on marker click, "listen" for click on each marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
     // animate marker
     // highlight the link associated with the marker.
});
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying and apologies for not getting back to you sooner. I thought about this and I think my requirements need to change. I'd still like to use a sidebar but as a slider rather than a drop down box. What I'd like to be able to do is if the user selects a marker on the map, the related link in the side bar will be highlighted and vice versa, again with the marker bouncing. But I must admit I haven't a clue where to start. I just wondered if you, or indeed anyone else had a few spare moments could you please show me what I need to do. Many thanks and regards Chris

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I'm a bit of beginner with Javscript so please bear with me. I've amended my code shown under UPDATE. I know I'm doing something wrong because instead of seeing a title 'Locations' with hyperlinks underneath. The title 'Locations' is the hyperlink. Could you perhaps please show me where I'm going wrong. Many thanks Chris

Comment: The anchor tag (<a>) can not be placed in the <head>! It can only appear in the body of the document. The closing bracket of the function getMarkerByName is commented and that leads to an error.
The links are not going to appear by themselves. You need to create one for each marker and add it to the document when creating the markers.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying. I think that I'll have to give this a break now, because from what you're saying I suspect that I need to gain a bit more knowledge of Javascript because I'm wouldn't even know where to begin to create the links. Many thanks for your time, trouble and help. Kind regards Chris